# Crop SWF using table?

Tags: html, css, flash

I am redoing our company website, and I have an older flash file I *have* to use. (Yep, one of those) The problem is this, on the old site, the swf was bigger than the bounding box, so they made a border inside of the swf file and used tables to "crop" the edges. So, when I put it on the nice shiny new site, I have this ugly border in the middle of my file.

I thought this would be as simple as setting the object embed code to a bigger size than it's surrounding box, and that works in Chrome, but not Firefox or IE.

```
<td style="overflow: hidden;" align="left" valign="top" width="250" height="180">    
<object style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; z-index: 1;" width="279" height="180" classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,40,0">
<param name="Movie" value="/HolidayVideo120108.swf" />
<param name="loop" value="false" />
<embed style="margin: -10px; padding: 0px; z-index: 1;" width="279" height="180" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="/HolidayVideo120108.swf" _cx="7381" _cy="4762" Movie="/HolidayVideo120108.swf" Src="/HolidayVideo120108.swf" loop="false" />
</object>
</td>
```

The original page is here: http://holidaysigns.com

New page is here: http://holidaysigns.com/wp

Pardon the mess, we're still renovating.

I've been playing with this for a while, but I can't come up with a solution that works in all three major browsers.

Comment: It might be better if you could just modify the swf.  Is the fla that created your swf gone?  If not, it may still be possible to open up the swf itself and modify it.  Do you *have* to use a table to contain it?

Comment: No sign of the original source files they used to make this.

Comment: Maybe this will help:  http://forums.adobe.com/message/4273423?tstart=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what was causing this to be so meh...

Moving from browser to browser, the page size was changing. (Since the browser windows were sized differently.) As the overall size of the page changed, the size of my table cell changed even though it was fixed width/height.

So, what I did was place a div in the table cell and set that to a fixed size.

```
<td align="left" valign="top">
<div style="overflow: hidden; padding: 0px; width: 250px; height: 162px;">
... embed swf ...
</div>
</td>
```

Now everything works as expected. Yay!